# Cant see my password

Tags: password

When setting up my username and password in the terminal of my Chromebook my password is simply not visible. I was able to type in my username but whatever I type in the password field is not visible.

Comment: this is by design, the password does not display, however it is being entered

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bader this is very common in Linux, passwords are usually concealed in the command line, but it will work anyway.